# Прописные в словах, входящих в состав наименования

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика

> В выделяемых кавычками наименованиях знаков отличия, названиях литературных произведений, газет, журналов, учреждений, предприятий и пр. пишутся с прописной буквы первое слово и входящие в их состав имена собственные ([«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/139-prop)).

Почему в наименованиях многих организаций с прописной буквы пишутся слова, которые не являются именами собственными?

1. «Тинькофф Банк».
2. «Азбука Вкуса».
3. «Альфа‑Банк».

И всё‑таки нужно писать эти наименования так, как установили сами организации, или так, как правильно с точки зрения норм: "Тинькофф банк", "Азбука вкуса", "Альфа‑банк"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под такими названиями многие организации зарегистрировались юридически, а при регистрации им не предъявлялись требования соответствия названия нормам языка. Названия менеджеры зачастую придумывают из подражания английским: в английском в некоторых именах допустимы заглавные буквы в середине слова (компания "МегаФон"), а все слова названия пишутся с заглавной. Отсюда АО «Тинькофф Банк», некорректные транслитерации фамилий и "английское" вставление прозвищ *между* именем и фамилией. Строго русским было бы напр. название *банк "Альфа"* (сначала идёт видовое наименование - если название не является эпитетом в духе "чудо-банка" или "альфа-самца").

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы высказать свою точку зрения по второй части вопроса: как авторам писать эти наименования в своих статьях в СМИ и в прочих публикациях?

Comment: Придётся так и писать - в соответствии с официальным названием.